# averaging a column of a file

Tags: awk, syntax

I have a CSV file (with time-stamped data), and I have a script
that will break each month of the year into a separate file. 
The script will take that month and average out the data to a single value. 
A portion of the code is below; all other months will do the same as the first for January.  The code will break the year long file into months based on column 9 (months are numbered 1-12) and will print all 17 fields. The next code line is to look at column 13 and average all data (ignoring all missing data, designated as -999) in the file and print the column average to the new $i.monthlyavg file.

```
awk -F ',' '$9= 1 {print $0}' $i > Jan.tmp
awk 'NR > 1 { for i = 13) if ($i != -999) {sum[i] += $i; num[i]++}
END { for (i = 13) print i, sum[i], num[i], sum[i]/num[i] }' Jan.tmp > $i.monthlyavg
```

I am getting in the following error messages.....

```
awk: cmd. line:1: NR > 1 { for i = 13) if (01-073-1003-SO2-1998.dat.out != -999) {sum[i] += 01-073-1003-SO2-1998.dat.out; num[i]++}
awk: cmd. line:1:              ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: NR > 1 { for i = 13) if (01-073-1003-SO2-1998.dat.out != -999) {sum[i] += 01-073-1003-SO2-1998.dat.out; num[i]++}
awk: cmd. line:1:                    ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: NR > 1 { for i = 13) if (01-073-1003-SO2-1998.dat.out != -999) {sum[i] += 01-073-1003-SO2-1998.dat.out; num[i]++}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: NR > 1 { for i = 13) if (01-073-1003-SO2-1998.dat.out != -999) {sum[i] += 01-073-1003-SO2-1998.dat.out; num[i]++}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                              ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: NR > 1 { for i = 13) if (01-073-1003-SO2-1998.dat.out != -999) {sum[i] += 01-073-1003-SO2-1998.dat.out; num[i]++}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                   ^ syntax error
```

and

```
 END { for (i = 13) print i, sum[i], num[i], sum[i]/num[i] }
awk: cmd. line:2:       ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:2:       END { for (i = 13) print i, sum[i], num[i], sum[i]/num[i] }
awk: cmd. line:2:                        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:2:       END { for (i = 13) print i, sum[i], num[i], sum[i]/num[i] }
awk: cmd. line:2:                                                                  ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You are missing the opening parenthesis in `for i = 13)` for one thing ...

Comment: If you have a column for months in the original data, there's no need to break it up into files by month.  You could just use the month to index into an array of totals and an array of counts for each month...

Comment: The first set of error messages indicates that you have your `awk` code in double quotes, but you show your `awk` commands in single quotes. Please double check that you are showing us exactly what you are using and that the error messages are for the commands that you say you use. There is no point in correcting errors in code that you don't use, and it's difficult to see the cause of errors in code that we can't see.

Comment: I see at https://stackoverflow.com/users/12921801/stormctr2 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/396038/stormctr2 that you've never accepted any answer to any of your questions on either forum. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/awk and then fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to average the numbers in column 13 for each separate value in column 9, there is no need to create separate files for each value in column 9.  Just keep track of separate sums and output them all at the end.

```bsh
awk -F, '
    $13 != -999 { s[$9] += $13; n[$9]++ }
    END { for (i in s) print i, s[i]/n[i] }' some-file
```

The main issue with your code is a syntax error in the way you've written the `for` loop. The `for` loop is not needed at all as we are only accessing the 13th column.

---

The `for` loop comes in two flavors in `awk`.  You have the "arithmetic `for` loop", which is the one you probably wanted to use.  It usually iterates with a counter from some initialization, until some logical test is no longer *true*, with some update:

```c
for (initialization; logical-test; update) statement
```

For example

```c
for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) print i
```

The other type is what I show in my answer above, and it's used to iterate over the indexes of an array.  Note that the loop may not iterate over the indexes in any particular order.

```c
for (index-variable in array) statement
```

For example

```c
for (key in data) print key, data[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

`for (i = 13)` simply is not a valid awk construct. 
(And do I really need to tell you that `for i = 13)`
isn’t even close to being syntactically valid?) 
The `for` statement has two versions:

- `for (expr1; expr2; expr3) statement`
- `for (var in array) statement`

It looks like you are trying to use the first one
(`for (expr1; expr2; expr3) statement`). 
If you wanted to look at all 17 fields, you could use `for (i = 1; i <= 17; i++)`, or, better yet, `for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)`. 
If you want to handle only field #13 but keep the loop structure,
you could use `for (i = 13; i <= 13; i++)`. 
But, if you want simple, straightforward code to do this specific job,
you could use

- `i = 13; if ($i != -999) {sum[i] += $i; num[i]++}`,
- `if ($13 != -999) {sum[13] += $13; num[13]++}`, or
- `if ($13 != -999) {sum += $13; num++}`

… because you don’t need arrays if you’re handling only one column.

And, as “they” commented, it looks *very very* much like you ran awk
with your program in double quotes. 
Things work *much much* better if you use single quotes.